# Scrollbar en submenus al desplegar menu

Tags: html, angularjs, nav

Tengo un menú html con la siguiente estructura, quiero hacer que si el menú tiene demasiados submenus salga un scroll bar, pero no veo la manera.

```
<nav >
              <ul>
                    <li">
                        <span>Menu Label</span>
                        <ul >
                            <li ng-repeat="subitems in menu.subMenus">
                               SubMenuLabel
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Y tu CSS?

Para eso tenés que agregar `overflow: auto` al `ul` que tiene la lista larga.

```
ul {
 overflow: auto;
}
```